# Odoo 10 js cache

Tags: odoo, odoo-10

I everyone, i have a problem developing a custom module on odoo 10.
When i modify a js or a css, imported into the view.xml in this way

```
    <template id="makeit.assets_common" name="makeit assets common" inherit_id="web.assets_common">
          <xpath expr="." position="inside">
            <!-- All links to CSS and JS files should be added in here. -->
            <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1/themes/flick/jquery-ui.css"/>
            <link href="/makeit/static/src/css/jquery.tagit.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/> 
            <script src="https://sdk.amazonaws.com/js/aws-sdk-2.171.0.min.js"></script>
            <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/crypto-js/3.1.9-1/crypto-js.js"></script>
            <script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/bluebird/3.5.0/bluebird.min.js"></script>
            <t t-call-assets="web.assets_backend" t-css="false"/>
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="/makeit/static/src/css/makeit.css"/>


<script type="text/javascript" src="/makeit/static/src/js/custom_js_v93.js"></script>


          </xpath>
        </template>
```

as you can see i have to change the name of the custom_js_v93 every time to make it work.
I've tried reloading db, odoo service, module ecc.
any idea? thank you

Comment: First, which browser are you using for? Second, it's so weird, when you adit an JS file, you just need to reload the page and nothing more, anyway you can use and incognito page, to dont make cache, and automaticaly clear cache on every reload.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your changes are in `*.py` files, restart the `odoo service`.

```
service odoo restart
```

If your changes are in existing `*.xml` files, re-install (upgrade) the module.

```
Apps > Your module > Upgrade
```

If your changes are in both, the do the both: restart the service then upgrade the module.

I don't think clearing browser cache is necessary, since Odoo automatically generates new `*.js` files (and removes the old ones) every service start:

```
http://odoo.example.com/web/content/6045-b6fe286/web.assets_backend.js
                                         ^
                                  This is generated
```

So in your case, just reinstall the module.

---

Updated:

Try changing to inheritance of `inherit_id="web.assets_backend"` if it fixes your issue:

```
<template id="makeit.assets_common" name="makeit assets common" inherit_id="web.assets_common">
```

to

```
<template id="makeit.assets_backend" name="makeit assets backend" inherit_id="web.assets_backend">
```

Comment: if i look into js you suggested me i don't find the code inside my custom_js. The code written inside the custom js should be inside the generated web.assets_backend.js?

Comment: i find that my code is present here http://custom.odoo.it/makeit,_static,_src,_js,_custom_js_v93.js+web_planner,_static,_src,_js,_web_planner_common.js+web_tour,_static,_src,_js,_tip.js+web_tour,_static,_src,_js,_tour_manager.js+web_tour,_static,_src,_js,_tour_service.js+web_editor,_static,_lib,_vkbeautify,_vkbeautify.0.99.00.beta.js+web_editor,_static,_src,_js,_ace.js+web_editor,_static,_src,_js,_base.js+web_editor,_static,_src,_js,_snippets.animation.js.pagespeed.jc.7-8ipddaYt.js but, even if i've reloaded module and restart odoo the content is still the same. I have to change the filename

Comment: That's weird that your JS is not found inside the `web.assets_backend.js`, your custom js should be there every time odoo service is started and page is loaded. How did you reload your module? And I do think the order of your reload things matter! (restart odoo first, then upgrade module)

Comment: Well, I just noticed that you have inherited `web.assets_common` instead. Try looking for your JS inside the compiled `web.assets_common.js` of Odoo. If your JS is not found either, try the code that I edited in my answer.